How to add a build and runtime checksum to Android AOSP system apps?
Want to add a build and runtime checksum to Android 12 or 13 AOSP or LinesgeOS Settings, TvSettings apps.
They must match for the app to open to prevent unpacking, tampering with the apps.
https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_TvSettings
https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Settings
I only find generic code not exact code to add for the above listed apps.

What you really want is secure boot, if someone can modify the SystemUI or Settings apps that means that they basically already have root, and if they have root then they can disable whatever hash checks you put in. I am assuming you control the hardware? If so then use secure boot: source.android.com/docs/security/features/verifiedboot . If you aren't controlling the hardware then you don't have much hope to control the software.
